# What benefits do I gain using BeginAccept vs a dedicated thread that blocks on Accept using TcpListener?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I was trying to think if I would get any scalability benefits from using BeginAccept vs just blocking in a dedicated thread waiting for connections.  Obviously, the individual clients are going to use BeginXXX/EndXXX pairs to utilize IOCP for network IO, but I'm thinking waiting on a client connection should have very low latency.  I plan on creating a Task to process incoming connections so my follow up code after the Accept is completed won't block the main accept thread for very long (long enough to create a Task object pretty much) and I can go right back to blocking on new connections.  This is pretty much what I would do with BeginAccept/EndAccept only without the complexities of managing the asynchronous call.

So, my question is what, if any, scaleability benefits do I get by using IOCP for accept?  Please note, this is not for sending / receiving on individual client sockets, but just for accepting connections on the server listening socket.

Comment: If your app wants to listen on 100 ports, do you want to waste 100MB of memory for 100 threads just blocking waiting for connections?

Comment: @JonSkeet interesting point, but if your app is listening on 100 ports you probably should reconsider the design of your app in the first place :D

Comment: You could listen only 1 port and reuse it (listen again) after you accept the incoming connection. Like the web server does on 80 port.

Comment: @AgentFire: No, I mean *really* listening on multiple ports - different numbers.

Comment: @Jon Not sure where you got that from, but I have ONE thread that BLOCKS on accept.  It's a SINGLE thread, not multiple threads that listen on multiple ports - that's madness.  I am also NOT spinning up threads for each client, but using BeginXXX/EndXXX IOCP calls.  My question was what IOCP benefits do I get with BeginAccept vs a blocking Accept?  Also, answering a question with another question is not very helpful.

Comment: @SRM: I was suggesting the scalability benefit *in general* is that you don't tie up a thread (and waste the relevant stack space). If you're only listening on a single port, that may not be important - but that's the benefit of asynchronously accepting the connection. And I completely disagree with the idea that asking questions in comments is passive-aggressive - I do so many, many times per day, as do many other users, usually to elicit more information. In this case it was to plant the seed of an idea. Oh, and I'm not the site founder, either. Perfectly fine day, thanks.

Comment: @Jon Okay, good point that it's <i>in general</i>.  I did ask a wide question so I should expect generic answers.  In my case, though, I am listening only on a single port and do not anticipate needing to listen on more than one.  I'm not trying to design the next best socket server framework, but trying to implement something quickly that will stand some test of time.

Comment: @SRM: Sure, so in that case you're only wasting one thread, with the stack space for one thread, and that's probably fine.

Comment: @Jon That's what I was thinking as well, but you do bring up a good point regarding the multiple threads.  I thought that BeginAccept had a bug though where if you had multiple TcpListeners calling it it would cause wonky things.  I remember chasing a bug in a repeater socket service for days because of that - not sure if they fixed that yet.

Comment: I think you'd have to give more details (ideally a repro case) before we could say anything meaningful about that. So, do you want me to post all of this as an answer?

Comment: @Jon Regarding the repro case, it was several years ago and that contract and corresponding code is long gone.  The bug had something to do with pinning and it was acknowledged by a MS tech (over the phone at least).  Again, all ancillary documentation for that belongs to the client, but I did speak with techs at MS over it.

Yes, please post this as an answer.  It is the answer to my question and I would like to accept it as such.  Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25384/discussion-between-srm-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 4):

If you only have a single port you're listening on, it probably isn't worth it - just like if you only need to deal with a few connections at a time, you may not bother using asynchronous operations to handle those.

The server-side benefit of asynchrony is usually when you scale up - for handling connections, it's when you get a lot of connections; for `BeginAccept` it's when you're listening on a lot of different ports. That's probably rarer, but if you ever *do* want to listen to 100 different ports (e.g. if you host lots of web sites on one server and for some reason want to just listen on different ports instead of using Host headers) then you don't want 100 threads sitting around just consuming stack space.